# None type object error when trying to use inherited Odoo object

Tags: python, class, inheritance, odoo, odoo-8

I am really stuck with this. I have created a new class in Odoo that I want call from a controller. This object needs to get data about a customer (res.partner) when I pass it an id field that I have created.

The problem I have is that I can't seem to call my parse method in my class. However I do it I get a nonetype object has not attribute parse.

What am I doing wrong? Am I a noob? And also am I making it harder than it needs to be?

Here is my class in a file called callback.py

```
__author__ = 'karl'
import requests
import json
from openerp import models, api
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class JiraParse(models.Model):
    _name = "res.parter"
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    def readname(self,jira_id):
        query = """
        SELECT name
        FROM res.partner
        WHERE jira_id = {0}
        """.format(jira_id)

        self.env.cr.execute(query)
        result = [(row[0], row[0]) for row in self.env.cr.fetchall()]
        _logger.info(str(result))
        return result

    def parse(self,data):
        #load json data
        R = json.loads(data)
        Customer = R['issue']['fields']['customfield_10128']
        CustomerId = R['issue']['fields']['customfield_10128']['id']
        issue_url = R['issue']['self']



        res = self.readname(CustomerId)
        _logger.info(str(res))
        #create dictionary/json callback object
        json_response = {'fields':
                             {'customfield_10128':{'value': 'ISYS Group'}
                              }}
        #json_response = Customer,CustomerId,issue_url
        #Make call back request to Jira to update customer data
        H = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        req = requests.post('http://10.10.15.39:5000', data=json.dumps(json_response), headers=H)
        return True
```

I am trying to call it from my controller like this:

```
t = callback.JiraParse()
t.parse(requestdata)
```

Where requestdata is a json object received by the controller.

All I get is this

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for calling your class method using class object.

```
t = JiraParse()
t.parse(requestdata)
```

Main reason behind for not calling your method directly because your method is not the static method so that we must have to make that parse method as static for directly access by your class name . so it is totally part of object oriented concept.

If it is in separate file then you must have to import the JiraParse class in your .py file.

```
from callback import JiraParse
t = JiraParse()
t.parse(requestdata)
```

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: I already have the import at the top of the controller. The issue is not with the import that works fine. As does instantiating the class. It is only when I come to call a method in the class it does not work.

Comment: Have to try to check out from first options